# How to create a middleware for the client side using nextauth in Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, middleware, next-auth

What would be a proper middleware to protect the pages /admin if the user does not have a session?
Is it correct the name of the file "_middleware.js" and what should I write inside that file to protect the route?

```
-pages
----admin
-----_middleware.js
-----index.js
```

_middleware.js

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
```

Gives the error:

*****[next-auth][error][NO_SECRET]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#no_secret*****

**.env**

```
 SECRET_KEY="SECRET_KEY"

NEXTAUTH_URL = "http://localhost:3000"

NEXTAUTH_SECRET_KEY="SECRET_KEY"
```

Comment: Have you had a read through https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#middleware?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, but still gives me the error that I did not have set the secret
this is printed in the console
[next-auth][error][NO_SECRET]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#no_secret

Comment: The environment variable for the secret has to be named `NEXTAUTH_SECRET`.

Comment: @juliomalves, I fixed that but now is redirected to sign up every time, even then I have token

Redirect to this: 
http://localhost:3000/auth/login?callbackUrl=http://localhost:3000/admin/categories